# Lipschitz with constant greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ implies $f(t) = \sum_{n \in Z} \hat{f}(n)e^{int} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, lipschitz-functions

While proving Bernstein theorem, our lecteur trivially used the following fact: 
$$f\in Lip_{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}),\;\; \alpha>1/2 \;\; \implies f(t) = \sum_{n \in Z}
\hat{f}(n)e^{int} $$  and the series converges at $L^{2}$ and at each point.

Is this true at all? If so, should this be immediate or it is a well-known result?  or it is a well-known result?

Comment: Maybe this might be of help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Absolute_convergence.

Comment: $f$ must be periodic for the above to make sense and then it is true by the general Dini-Lipschitz criterion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%E2%80%93Lipschitz_criterion